# Bluetooth over uart using hciattach?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, kernel-module, bluez, hci

I am using `QN9021` SoC working in `controller mode` (BLE Bluetooth core specification v4.0). It supports some standard `HCI` commands as well as some vendor specific commands. I am trying to attach it in my `ubuntu` laptop.

The command that i have used is `hciattach`.

```
hciattach -s 9600 /dev/ttyUSBx any 9600 noflow nosleep
```

The `hcidump` shows while executing `sudo hciconfig hci1 up`.

```
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 5.37
device: hci1 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0xffffffffffffffff
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 12
    Read Local Supported Features (0x04|0x0003) ncmd 11
    status 0x00
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 12
    Read Local Version Information (0x04|0x0001) ncmd 11
    status 0x00
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6) HCI Revision: 0x400
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6) LMP Subversion: 0x400
    Manufacturer: Quintic Corp. (142)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 10
    Read BD ADDR (0x04|0x0009) ncmd 11
    status 0x00 bdaddr 08:7C:BE:3E:34:BB
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 11
    Read Buffer Size (0x04|0x0005) ncmd 11
    status 0x00
    ACL MTU 0:0 SCO MTU 0:0
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4
    Read Class of Device (0x03|0x0023) ncmd 11
    status 0x01 class 0x000000
    Error: Unknown HCI Command
```

The `hciconfig` command shows:

```
hci1:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: UART
    BD Address: 08:7C:BE:3E:34:BB  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:192 acl:0 sco:0 events:15 errors:0
    TX bytes:60 acl:0 sco:0 commands:15 errors:0

hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: C4:8E:8F:66:3B:0E  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:2457 acl:0 sco:0 events:196 errors:0
    TX bytes:24646 acl:0 sco:0 commands:196 errors:0
```

I would like to know how to prevent the kernel or some bluetooth kernel module to send non-supported HCI commands. Do i need to patch linux kernel source code or write a module for my SoC.

Note:- Changing the SoC or writing firmware for it to support all necessary commands is not possible for this project.

---

EDIT:

I know the list of `HCI`command supported by my SoC. I am thinking of creating a `module` to tell the kernel and daemons running to send only supported commands to the SoC. I have a look at linux kernel source (specifically at this [hci_core.c](https://github.com/abhiarora4/linux/blob/master/net/bluetooth/hci_core.c)). I think modifying it may solve the problem after going through this [link](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60901#c5). In this link, some developer has provided a patch to support a `bluetooth dongle`. The patch prevents the [hci_core.c](https://github.com/abhiarora4/linux/blob/master/net/bluetooth/hci_core.c) file to send a specific HCI command to a dongle of a particular manufacturer.

All i want is suggestion to resolve this problem. Do i need to modify the linux kernel or write a module for my SoC?

NOTE:- The application will run on `openwrt` linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem few years back. I was using Linux version `4.4.14` and Bluez stack `5.38`. Looks like `QN9021` had some bugs. The problem wasn't with `Read Class of Device` but with the response given by `QN9021` for the command: `Read Local Supported Features`. Since, it's the BLE controller chip, it shouldn't be sending `Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00` as the response to the above command.

The issue is kernel detects it as Classic Bluetooth controller chip and then sends non-supported HCI commands to the chip. The chip should have set the 5th and 6th bits ([LMP_NO_BREDR](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/net/bluetooth/hci.h) and [LMP_LE](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/net/bluetooth/hci.h) bits) of the 4th byte in the `Features` to the command `Read Local Supported Features` and then kernel detects it as a `BLE` controller mode chip and won't send any unsupported commands to a ble controller mode chip.

Since, I can't change the firmware of the chip, I had to patch the kernel.

Here are my patches:

```
*** hci_event.c 2017-02-10 00:05:13.149974000 +0530
--- bluetooth/hci_event.c   2016-06-24 22:48:38.000000000 +0530
***************
*** 588,597 ****
    if (rp->status)
        return;

- 
    memcpy(hdev->features, rp->features, 8);
-   hdev->features[0][4] |= LMP_NO_BREDR;
-   hdev->features[0][4] |= LMP_LE;

    /* Adjust default settings according to features
     * supported by device. */
--- 588,594 ----
```

I have also tired the following command but it didn't helped:

```
hciattach -r /dev/ttyS0 bcsp 115200
```

Answer (score 6):

Okay, today we found out the solution:

```
# hciattach -r /dev/ttyS0 bcsp 115200
```

Maybe it helps somebody

Helpful Tips:May this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/wireless-hacks-2nd/0596101449/ch01.html) will be helps to you.

> I will give two links for more details
>   and for bluetooth [click here](http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/wireless/bluetooth)
>   and for kernel configuration [click here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.6/general/bluez.html)

Comment: And for the bluetooth and kernel i will give two links for more details,

Comment: I tried raw mode but it didn't help. I have applied a patch in kernel and my device works now. I will post my patch and other details soon

Comment: You answer didn't helped me. I have posted my answer and solution. Have a look